# I want to use cosine similarity to identify the intent and pass it to RASA Core

Tags: rasa-nlu, rasa-core

I want to use cosine similarity to identify the intent and pass it to RASA Core. In other words, I want to replace the NLU part with some other similarity calculation method.
How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is four classifiers implemented in Rasa-NLU:

- [sklearn_intent_classifier](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_nlu/blob/master/rasa_nlu/classifiers/sklearn_intent_classifier.py)
- [mitie_intent_classifier](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_nlu/blob/master/rasa_nlu/classifiers/mitie_intent_classifier.py)
- [keyword_intent_classifier](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_nlu/blob/master/rasa_nlu/classifiers/keyword_intent_classifier.py)
- [embedding_intent_classifier](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_nlu/blob/master/rasa_nlu/classifiers/embedding_intent_classifier.py)

If you use [`embedding_intent_classifier.py`](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_nlu/blob/master/rasa_nlu/classifiers/embedding_intent_classifier.py) by default it is used cosine similarity:

```
"similarity_type": 'cosine',  # string 'cosine' or 'inner'
```

*How to customize your pipeline?*

```
language: "en"

pipeline:
- name: "tokenizer_whitespace"
- name: "ner_crf"
- name: "ner_synonyms"
- name: "intent_featurizer_count_vectors"
- name: "intent_classifier_tensorflow_embedding"
```

See [here](https://rasa.com/docs/nlu/choosing_pipeline/) for more details.

*How to define my own Components?*

Inherit from parent object `Component` and implement your own. If you need to define `tfidf` and `cosine` read [here](https://rasa.com/docs/nlu/customcomponents/), and then compare your code with [here](https://github.com/RasaHQ/rasa_nlu/blob/master/rasa_nlu/classifiers/sklearn_intent_classifier.py).

```
from rasa_nlu.components import Component

class MyComponent(Component):
 def __init__(self, component_config=None):
     pass

 def train(self, training_data, cfg, **kwargs):
     pass

 def process(self, message, **kwargs):
     pass

 def persist(self, model_dir):
     pass

 @classmethod
 def load(cls, model_dir=None, model_metadata=None, cached_component=None,
          **kwargs):
```

Also do not forget to add it into pipeline:

```
pipeline:
- name: "MyComponent"
```

Comment: I want to use tf-idf vectorizer and then cosine similarity to find the best match. How to do it.